# How to correctly load data from a table to a form?

Tags: django, orm

The full branch with the problems is here:

https://github.com/bethlakshmi/GBE2/tree/GBE-459

The problem is:

First - I have a form that requires valid items in a given data object:

```
from [EventScheduleForm][1]:


class EventScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'
    error_css_class = 'error'

    day = forms.ChoiceField(choices=conference_days)
    time = forms.ChoiceField(choices=conference_times)
    location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[
            (loc, loc.__str__()) for loc in
            LocationItem.objects.all().order_by('room__name')])
    duration = DurationFormField(
               help_text=scheduling_help_texts['duration'])
...
```

Next - I have a unit test that seeds some Room objects via a fixture and then tries to commit a submit to the form:

```
class TestEditEvent(TestCase):
    '''Tests for edit_event view'''

    ''' Fixture to create some rooms, location items, and resource items '''
    fixtures = ['scheduler/fixtures/rooms.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.s_event = factories.SchedEventFactory.create()
        self.profile_factory = factories.ProfileFactory
        self.client = Client()
        self.room = Room.objects.all().order_by('name').first()
        self.s_event.set_location(self.room)

    ...

    def test_edit_event_submit_succeed(self):
        '''edit event post succeeds without errors'''
        profile = self.profile_factory.create()
        form_post = self.get_edit_event_form()
        request = self.factory.post('/scheduler/create/GenericEvent/%d' %
                               self.s_event.pk,
                               form_post)
        request.user = profile.user_object
        functions.grant_privilege(profile, 'Scheduling Mavens')
        rooms = Room.objects.all().order_by('name')
        for loc in rooms:
            print "Room:" + loc.__str__() + "| \n"
        response = edit_event(request, self.s_event.pk, "GenericEvent")

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        print(response.content)
        self.assertFalse('<font color="red">!</font>' in response.content)
        self.assertTrue(form_post['title'] in response.content)
        self.assertTrue(form_post['description'] in response.content)
```

What I find is that the line of code:

```
location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[
            (loc, loc.__str__()) for loc in
            LocationItem.objects.all().order_by('room__name')])
```

Is failing.  It acts as if there are NO rooms, but the print statements show that the room is properly set and seen in the unit test.

What is wrong with this line?  Is there a better/different way to load the list of room choices that would work differently?

It works in integration - but we've had trouble where we have to restart the database or otherwise tinker with it to get this part of the code to work properly - so something is not right about how it's pulling from the database.

Other notes:
- Django 1.6 & 1.6.5
- SQL Lite and MySQL 
- Linux/Mac
- Apache and native Django server

have been my baselines

Answer (score 0):

You could change your that ChoiceField to a ModelChoiceField

```
     location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=LocationItem.objects.all().order_by('room__name')
```

Here's some documentation that might help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield